# Some apps shown twice in dock when using Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, dock, interface

I just started using Gnome Shell and so far I love it. However, I added some of my frequently used apps as favourites to the dock, and some of them show up twice when launched. Once as if they are not running and then another that IS running, but with a low-rez icon.

So far this has happened with:

- Komodo IDE
- SmartGit
- SmartSVN

It's quite annoying. I assume this happens because these apps run 2 processes, the first of which (that is used in the `.desktop` shortcuts) is just a bash script that sets environment variables and applies some logic prior to launching the actual program.

Does anyone know if there's any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

i found the answer in another [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403766/duplicate-icons-for-manully-created-gnome-launcher-items)

1. Launch the application
2. Fire up a terminal and run `xprop WM_CLASS`. Click the application window.
3. You'll get some output like `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox"`. Choose one of the classes, eg `Firefox` in this example
4. Add the class as the value of `StartupWMClass` in the `.desktop` file. For example, `StartupWMClass=Firefox`
5. Save the `.desktop` file, close the application and re-open it. There should now only be 1 icon in the launcher