# Duplicate icons for manually created GNOME launcher items

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, .desktop, aptana-studio

I have downloaded Aptana Studio 3 and created the following launcher item for using Alacarte:

file: `alacarte-made.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Terminal=false
Name=Aptana Studio 3
Exec=AptanaStudio3
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/Aptana-Studio-3/icon.xpm
```

Then, when I add the icon to the favorites and opens the Aptana Studio 3 I get two icons for it, one for launching new instances, and one for the currently running instance as per the following screenshot:

[image]

How do I force the application to use the same icon added to the favorites?

Comment: Can you please specify how you installed Aptana? From the official site all I can see is a standalone zip file. (something like portable applications in windows).

Comment: Yes, that was it.

Comment: So, how did it end up in `/opt`? Also, is it on your `$PATH`? How by specifying only `AptanaStudio3` in your desktop file it is able to run?

Comment: I have done it, thank you.
I have created a Sym Link in /usr/bin to /opt/.../aptana
It was just a mater of naming issue. I had to name the .desktop and bin and link just the same :)

Comment: Please answer in detail below how you managed to solve your problem :) (I don't know, I only asked you some questions)

Comment: So, have you solved the problem with duplicate icons? If so, please create a detailed answer.

Comment: I will try to do so :)
I am busy these days...

Comment: This works and fixed the same problem I had with popcorn-time favorite I added to the gnome bar on ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 104):

To save sifting through the thread mentioned by @earthmeLon, you need to do the following:

1. Launch the application
2. Fire up a terminal and run `xprop WM_CLASS`. Click on the window of the the application that is running with a duplicate icon.
3. You'll get some output like `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox"`. Choose one of the classes, eg `Firefox` in this example
4. Add the class as the value of `StartupWMClass` in the `.desktop` file. For example, `StartupWMClass=Firefox`
5. Save the `.desktop` file, close the application and re-open it. There should now only be 1 icon in the launcher

Comment: For those having the same issue on GNOME you can use MenuLibre: When editing the corresponding entry you will find a field for setting StatupWMClass in the list that shows up when clicking the "Advanced" button

Comment: If someone is trying to handle an issue with `mendeley` executable, make sure to also edit `.../bin/install-mendeley-link-handler.sh`, because it overrides `.desktop` file on each run

Comment: **TLDR;** *.desktop filename = WM_CLASS(STRING) last item but lowercased. **Details:** I had to solve this issue while creating "Firefox Developer edition" shortcut. Naming the file "firefox.desktop" simply shadowed the standard firefox icon. Using xprop WM_CLASS and clicking the window returned WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox Developer Edition". In the end I renamed my .desktop file as follows: mv ffde.desktop "firefox developer edition.desktop". (Another issue though, I can not right-click » addToFavorites on the icon from the gnome dock extension)

Comment: If you don't want to / can't to modify the original .desktop file into the /usr/share/applications folder, you can copy the file to your local folder, ~/.local/share/applications, and modify the file here. So you will have a system-wide original file (probably provided by the developer/distribution) and a customized file which overrides the original file in the gnome-shell applications panel. Copying to your local folder is desirable as the file into /usr/share/applications can be reversed in the next package update.

Comment: Several apps don't have WM_CLASS, or at least xprop doesn't show it. Can it be done with another property? For example a regular expression on WM_NAME?

Comment: Accept this answer already :)

Comment: Was suffering from this for so long. This comment did it for me. Thank you!

Comment: No. Useless in Ubuntu 20

Comment: It still works in Gnome 3.38.

Comment: Works ok on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for saving me twice. I would have gave you another up-vote, but I unfortunately can't.

Comment: What a wonderfully simple fix! I'll note, though, that when the instructions say "click on the window", they mean **on** the window. Simply switching to the application (e.g. by clicking on its app icon) isn't enough to trigger `xprop`.

Answer (score 4):

### StartupWMClass

You can use StartupWMClass to group windows by class.

See [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/367851/13247) for additional information.

Comment: In addition, make sure: (1) There's no other desktop file for the same app, also in "AppEditor" or in "Main Menu". (2) Verify that `Exec=/path/to/app` is an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS** and I installed **Firefox Developer Edition Version=109.0**

I came up with same problem, Here I paste my .desktop code,

**Before (Wrong):-**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Mozilla Firefox
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;text/mml;
StartupNotify=True
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
Version=109.0
```

**After (Working):-**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Mozilla Firefox
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;text/mml;
StartupNotify=True
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
Version=109.0
StartupWMClass=firefox-aurora
```

Now its working correctly.

**Hint:-**

I tried all the above answers before posting my answer(this),

1. Launch the application
2. Fire up a terminal and run `xprop WM_CLASS`. Click on the window of the the application that is running with a duplicate icon.

When I run `xprop WM_CLASS` , I can't see any output as mentioned in those answers.

**Then how do I solve this?**

> When I mouse over the additional app icon in taskbar, It displayed `firefox-aurora`

I just read the `application.ini` file from firefox installation folder and found `RemotingName=firefox-aurora` so I copied **firefox-aurora** name to `StartupWMClass=firefox-aurora`

In place of `firefox-aurora` I also tried `firefox` (because its the executable file name), but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score -2):

I faced this issue when I manually installed [Spring Tool Suite 4](https://download.springsource.com/release/STS4/4.12.0.RELEASE/dist/e4.21/spring-tool-suite-4-4.12.0.RELEASE-e4.21.0-linux.gtk.x86_64.tar.gz)

Then, after install, I created [STS.desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kncGx.png) in following [folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB6uI.png) of [Ubuntu 20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lkAx.png)

Comment: Paste the text of the commands, instead of links to images.