# Run .desktop command verbose

Tags: command-line, launcher, .desktop

I'm trying to create a launcher for skilion's onedrive from [here.](https://github.com/skilion/onedrive)
I've already built it and it's in my PATH. I'm trying to create a launcher with an icon that will invoke `onedrive -m` in a terminal window so I can see files being uploaded and whatnot. This is what I have so far:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=OneDrive
Icon=/home/{me}/script/OneDrive-icon.png
Exec=onedrive -m
```

When I launch this, I just see an empty terminal. If I create a file in my OneDrive folder, the terminal doesn't show anything being uploaded. If I open a terminal and enter `onedrive -m` the normal way, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here's a picture of what the command will do normally. I want the launcher to open a window that does this continually until I stop it.

[image]

Comment: see also http://askubuntu.com/q/436891/295286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more line

```
Terminal=true
```

If the command requires you keeping terminal open for some time, you can alter the `Exec` line like so:

```
Exec=bash -c 'onedrive -m;bash'
```

Comment: I already had the line `Terminal=true`

Comment: @TheDetective OK, is this a long-running command or does it exit fairly fast ? You said you see empty terminal. Is the command supposed to output text or  does it exit silently  normaly ?

Comment: It's supposed to monitor the contents of my OneDrive folder locally and remotely, and upload/download files. I'll try to post a picture shortly of some example output.

Comment: Try the edit i made to the answer

Comment: It's working now, thanks! Is there any way to make the terminal window that is open stay attached to the Icon in the launcher, instead of becoming part of the terminal in the launcher?

Comment: @TheDetective technically, yes, there is a way; see this: http://askubuntu.com/a/635839/295286