# Firefox Web Browser icon is seperate to running icon

Tags: gnome, firefox, dock

### The Issue

In the applications menu, Firefox Web Browser appears with the correct name.

When launching, it's name changes to just Firefox, and its icon appears as a greyscale version, instead of the usual symbolic version.

This is not particularly annoying - just a minor inconsistency, but it means that the running Firefox icon is separate to the pinned icon.

I did recently install Firefox inside wine, which added a new shortcut, but I don't see how it could conflict.

The last time I encountered this issue was in Windows 7 and with Google Chrome, so it's been a while.

I have tried reinstalling Firefox, but that didn't help.

If I favourite Firefox instead of Firefox Web Browser, the icon won't launch anything. If I favourite Firefox Web Browser, it will launch as a separate icon.

There may have been some background updates (I kept automatic updates on for security reasons - I don't usually bother to install them otherwise).

I can probably manage this small issue, it just may be a bit hard to get used to having the icon in two different places. I don't want to pin them next to each other, because that looks even weirder - I'm already used to some non-native apps having this issue.

Edit: It seems to be related to Wine, as when launching from the new logo, Wine starts up, before closing again.

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate icons for manually created GNOME launcher items](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403766/duplicate-icons-for-manually-created-gnome-launcher-items)

Comment: That question is different, as this has broken an existing application.

Comment: Yes but did you try any of the solutions suggested?

Comment: This problem is that the icon is grouping to the wrong application, unlike the other problem which is that there is no grouping at all. Unfortunately, I can't test whether the other answer fixes this, but I don't think it does.

Comment: Thank you anyway, as it means that I can finally fix the Eclipse IDE icon! That issue has now been annoying me for about two years (when I switched back to Ubuntu from Linux Mint).

Answer (score 0):

It didn't take me long to realise that this was directly related to Wine.

I hid the duplicate version of Firefox in my menu, but Firefox Web Browser must have picked up the other desktop file.

I fixed this by removing "~/.local/share/applications/Firefox.desktop" and "~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/Firefox.desktop".

If this happens to you, don't use Wine if the software is already available in Linux. I was just doing this for fun to see what happened.
If you do want to do this, make sure to remove the desktop files properly, otherwise you may encounter issues.

I have had similar issues with desktop files, such as adding a Java-based application to my menu, and all Java processes appearing with the same icon in System Monitor.